# highchart tooltip with multiple additional data in tooltip?

Tags: highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I m using Dotnet Highchart. I m getting data from a data base table which has 10 columns in total and using its two columns to display chart.

I need to show all 10 columns in tooltip (sort of summary), but I dont have an idea  if it can be done or not ? Can you please guide me how to pass data of all columns to table and display in tooltip ?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: How your data looks like ? Each column is separe serie? if yes, then you can use shared parameter http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared. In other cases you need to use toolitp formatter and display all values.

Answer (score 0):

if you are maintaining the entire data to be plotted in a separate list/array you can access it from the formatter function of the tooltip

```
tooltip: {
formatter: function() {
//apply your logic here like a regular js method
//the returned value will be displayed on tooltip
return this.y; 
}
}
```

refer api documentation : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks @strikers, but I need to show values from columns other then X-Axis and Y-Axis as well. To chart I can pass maximum 3 columns of data. I appropriate your reply.

Comment: sorry I didn't get you!!